# Share value between views in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have  apage with 3 options and each option represent a group of permissions. I have the groupName in my view permissionsConfig but when I edit one group I lose the name of the group and i need the name to make a request to my rest api.

```
organizationsController.js

app.controller('OrganizationsPermissionsSettingsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modal', 'HelperService', 'AuthService', '$state', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $modal, HelperService, AuthService, $state, $http) {
        var controllerScope = $scope;                              
        controllerScope.organizationGroups = [];

        $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups').success(function (data) {
            controllerScope.organizationGroups = data;
        });

        controllerScope.openOrganizationPermissionsSettings = function (organizationId) {
            $state.go('app.organizationPermissionsSettings');
        };

        var groupId = "";

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            if(document.getElementById("permissionGroupName").innerHTML!=null){
                groupName=document.getElementById("permissionGroupName").innerHTML;
                console.log("groupName ",groupName);
                $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups/getId'+groupName).success(function (data) {
                    if(data != undefined && data != null){
                        groupId=data;
                        console.log("controllerScope.id ",groupId);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $scope.navigateToGraphs = function() {
            $state.go('app.organizationGraphs', { groupId: groupId });
            // then get parameter groupId
            $state.params.groupId;          
        }

        $scope.navigateToViews = function() {
            $state.go('app.organizationViews', { groupId: groupId });
            // then get parameter groupId
            $state.params.groupId;
        }   
    }]);

app.controller('OrganizationGraphsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', 'HelperService', '$http', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $scope, HelperService, $http, $stateParams) {

            var controllerScope = $scope;

            controllerScope.graphData = {};

            $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups/graphs/'+$stateParams.groupId).success(function (data) {

                controllerScope.graphData = data.graphs;
            });

            controllerScope.saveOptions = function () {
                $http.put('/api/organization_permissions_groups/graphs/'+$stateParams.groupId, controllerScope.graphData).then(function (response) { 

                    }, function () { });
                HelperService.editItem(id, controllerScope.graphData, null, 'Graphs', '/api/organization_permissions_groups/graphs/');                            
            }

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss();
            };
        }
    ]);

organizationPermissionsConfigView.html
```

here I have `<td id="permissionGroupName">{{organizationGroup.group_name}}</td>` which retrive my permission group name.

I have 3 groups at the moment and with the group name i make a rest api request to get the id and with that id i can make updates on the permission group understand?

Comment: it is not very clear in your code between what you want to share the value (no time to analyse all the code, it would have been better to provide a minimal example), but when i had to do this, i created a service for global data that needs to be shared between controllers. Each controller can import the service and get the value from there

Comment: Normally in angularJS ,there are two methods to be followed to share the values between controllers.1.Services 2.$rootScope.Use anyone of this

Comment: I tried $rootScope but it dont goes in "document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { " cause I have a table and if i dont have everything loaded I will get the erro for the td dom element that it is null...